# Sharepoint Lists.GetListItems sorting

Tags: c#, sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-api

I am making a call to Lists.GetListItems web method of sharepoint through my c# code. Is it possible to get sorted list from the sharepoint? Or do I have to sort it after retrieval in my c# code? I was not able to find any option in query or queryOptions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems.aspx

GetListItems contains a parameter 'query'. If you pass an xml node in that query with something like:

```
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='fieldnametosort' /></OrderBy>
```

You'll get a sorted list returned.

Answer (score 0):

For us this worked.

```
<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>
```

Notice the extra `<Query>` around `<OrderBy>`. We tried `ows_Modified` as the name, that didn't work.